# MySql :: using temp table in while loop

Tags: mysql, while-loop, temp-tables

Can I use Temp table within While Loop in MySQL

like :

```
WHILE (@CurrIndex <= @RowsCount) DO
SELECT FileReference,FileID,AllowDelete,ReferenceID  
       FROM deletefilesreferences LIMIT 1; 

    END WHILE;
```

Where  **`deletefilesreferences`**  is temp table.

Comment: but Unfortunately, I tried to do that but it gives error that that table is not exist

Comment: The temporary table exists in a session where it was created.